# Gracefully quit from mex file if there is a memory allocation error

Tags: c++, matlab, exception, memory-management, mex

I have a mex function that takes a double precision input vector, downcasts the precision to a temporary single precision vector, does some processing and then upcasts the result of the processing to double precision again.

The following simplified code example compiles and illustrates this process.

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{           
  int xM = mxGetM(prhs[0]); 
  int xN = mxGetN(prhs[0]);         
  int totalNumElements = xM*xN;       

  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(xM,xN,mxREAL);

  double* out  = mxGetPr(plhs[0]); 
  double* in   = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);    

  float out32[totalNumElements]; 
  float  in32[totalNumElements]; 

  // ---------> DOWNCAST <---------
  for (int mm = 0; mm < totalNumElements; ++mm)
      in32[mm] = (float)in[mm];
  // ---------- DOWNCAST ----------

  // Do some single precision signal processing (just copy for this example)
  for (int mm = 0; mm < totalNumElements; ++mm)
      out32[mm] = in32[mm];

  // ---------> UPCAST <---------
  for (int mm = 0; mm < totalNumElements; ++mm)
      out[mm] = (double)out32[mm];
  // ---------- UPCAST ---------- 
}
```

On my machine, calling the compiled mex function like this works fine . .

```
>> x = randn(1e6,1); y=demo(x);
```

...but calling it like this causes Matlab to close unexpectedly

```
>> x = randn(1e7,1); y=demo(x);
```

Seeing as the crash is caused by an increase in the size of the input vector, I'm guessing that the error is due to a failed memory allocation. How can I gracefully quit to Matlab giving an error message if such an error occurs? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `try`-`catch` clauses?

Comment: `float out32[totalNumElements]` throws an exception if it fails, does it?

Comment: @learnvst, no, that allocation will just cause *stack overflow*, cough.

Comment: I have posted some solutions below. Is there any way to detect a failed stack allocation?

Comment: You allocate a lot of memory on the stack.. Dont use this float out32[totalNumElements];. Allocate dynamic memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Method 1**

OK, one way to do this would be to replace the stack allocated variables with the C-style . . .

```
 float*  in32  =  (float*)mxCalloc(totalNumElements, sizeof(float));
 float*  out32 =  (float*)mxCalloc(totalNumElements, sizeof(float));
```

When there is a memory error, Matlab neatly gives the following error . . .

> Error using demo Out of memory.
>
> Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

No need for `try-catch` blocks or exceptions.

## **Method 2**

Another method is to use C++ style `std::exception`. The stack allocated variables can be replaced with the following ...

```
  float*  in32;
  float*  out32;
  try
  {
      in32  = new float[totalNumElements];
      out32 = new float[totalNumElements];
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
      std::string msg = std::string("Aw snap: ") + e.what();
      mexErrMsgTxt(msg.c_str());
  }
```

When there is a memory error, Matlab neatly gives the following error . . .

> Error using demo
>
> Aw snap: std::bad_alloc

## **Notes**

Method 1 is more compact and better integrated with the mex API. It is probably best to use method 1 in the mex gateway function and method 2 in a library that may have uses beyond just making a Matlab extension. Both these methods require you to use `mxFree` (`mxCalloc` solution) or `delete` (`new` solution) in order to fee the memory allocated on the heap for `in32` and `out32`. I still don't know how to detect or deal with stack overflows